# How to use bound value in isolate scope in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive.  I want to use an attribute value of that directive in my directive's controller.  I attempt to do this by binding the attribute value to my isolate scope.  However I run into a problem in that the attribute value seems not to be immediately bound to the isolate scope.

Consider the following code:

```
angular.module('startup.directives.decision', [])

    .directive('decisionMaker', [function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'views/directives/decision.html',
            scope: {
                decisionType:"@",
            }, 
            controller: ['$scope', 'Decisions', function ($scope, Decisions){

                //this prints undefined
                console.log($scope.decisionType);

                //this prints the proper value when called a couple seconds after page load
                $scope.getDecisionType = function(){
                    console.log($scope.decisionType);
                };

                //this is my motivation for wanting $scope.decisionType to be bound immediately
                if($scope.decisionType==='hire'){
                    //should do some stuff here
                }
            }]
        };
    }]);
```

I call my directive like this:

```
<decision-maker decision-type="investment"></decision-maker>
<decision-maker decision-type="hire"></decision-maker>
```

Comment: How are you calling the directive (HTML)? What is the scope of the template that is calling the directive?

Comment: Hi Nikos, I think this problem should be independent of the scope that is calling the directive.  The only thing I'm trying to get is the attribute value of the directive.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of this? I am using a seemingly same case where `$scope.decisionType` is available immediately. Something is smelly here...

Comment: I don't unfortunately.  Although if you have a fiddle of something similar that connects the attribute value to the scope before the beginning of the controller execution, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Yeap, I almost went crazy on that thank you :) It seems NOT to be working for Angular 1.1.1 ([fiddle 1.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/nDmnQ/). Yet it IS working for 1.2 (and in my case 1.1.4) ([fiddle 1.2](http://jsfiddle.net/AYvKd/)). Yupi!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to use the `$observe` function. See the Attributes section of the [Directives documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

So, something like this:

```
        controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', 'Decisions', function ($scope, $attrs, Decisions){

            //this prints undefined
            console.log($scope.decisionType);

            //this prints the proper value when called a couple seconds after page load
            $scope.getDecisionType = function(){
                console.log($scope.decisionType);
            };

            $attrs.$observe('decisionType', function(value) {
                //this is my motivation for wanting $scope.decisionType to be bound immediately
                if($scope.decisionType==='hire'){
                    //should do some stuff here
                }

            });
        }]
```

Comment: This solution did not work in the case where I am using this directive within an ng-repeat.  However if I used $scope.$watch in place of $attrs.$observe I did have success.  See this issue report:https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1941

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to access my attributes by binding them with the scope, I can access them more directly via the $attrs object!

```
angular.module('startup.directives.decision', [])

    .directive('decisionMaker', [function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'views/directives/decision.html',
            scope: {}, 
            controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', 'Decisions', function ($scope, $attrs, Decisions){

                //this prints the correct value
                console.log($attrs.decisionType);

                if($attrs.decisionType==='hire'){
                    //should do some stuff here
                }
            }]
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: That will work as long as you never have an interpolated (`{{}}`) value for the attribute. If you are wanting to use `{{}}` in the value of the attribute, the `$attrs` object will give you undefined. Thus the need for the `$observe` function.

Comment: good point! however I ran into an issue with $observe also... see my comment to your answer